# Why is "the ball of the foot" called as it is?

Tags: meaning

I understand the ball of a foot is  where the toes join with the rest of the foot. But I don't think it looks like a ball. Why is it called a "ball"?

Comment: Did you read the faq?

Answer (score 9):

Actually it is because it looks like a ball. It is fairly prominent in this image*:

[image]

The [ball of the foot](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ball+of+foot) is: "The padded portion of the sole of the human foot between the toes and the arch, on which the weight of the body rests when the heel is raised."

*Image from http://www.drcomfort.com/your-feet/ball

Comment: Thanks! Which part is called the toe, the part below the big toe, or the part below the five toes? The former looks partially like a ball, but the latter doesn't. BTW: when measuring foot size, the measurement for ball is the circumference for the borderline between all five toes and the arch, which suggests the ball is the part below five toes.

Comment: @Tim, did you mean to ask which part is called the *ball*? You are right, it's the part below all five toes. As the definition I cited says, it is the part on which your body weight rests when the heel is raised. However, it is named for the largest metatarsal bone that looks like a ball. http://visual.merriam-webster.com/human-being/anatomy/skeleton/foot.php

Comment: All my life I believed the ball to be obviously the round portion ...at the back ...the heel.